# Cannot add Cordova plugin - Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I followed [this](https://moduscreate.com/blog/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios/) tutorial about how to write Cordova plugin.
Now I'm trying to add the plugin into my iOS project like this :

```
cd /Users/Admin/Desktop/testpluginswift/testapp 
cordova plugin add /Users/Admin/Desktop/testpluginswift/TestPluginSwift/
```

Then I got this errors :

> (node:11661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Invalid Plugin! /Users/Admin/Desktop/testpluginswift/TestPluginSwift/ needs a valid package.json
>
> (node:11661) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So what I did was :

```
plugman createpackagejson /Users/Admin/Desktop/testpluginswift/TestPluginSwift/
```

But now I get this error:

> (node:11528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError
>
> (node:11528) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How can I solve this problems?
thanks

Comment: i am facing same issue have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downgrade the Cordova version to 7.1.0 and use `--nofetch` option when installing, that way you won't need the package.json file.

Also, you can provide the package.json that was created so we can see if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Can you please help me to figure out with Cordova version: 8.0.0

Comment: Is it the same error message? I don't mean the 'Unhandled promise rejection' part, but the rest of the error.

Comment: node:4863) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError
(node:4863) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: hard to tell if it's the same problem, can you run the command with `--verbose` param at the end?

Comment: No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "/CustomPlugin/myCustomPlugin"
saving
Running command: npm install /CustomPlugin/myCustomPlugin --production --save
Command finished with error code 1: npm install,/CustomPlugin/myCustomPlugin,--production,--save